# Find projection matrix using partitioned matrices

Tags: regression, matrix, linear-algebra, projection

If $X$ is a *($n$, $p+1$)* design matrix, partition $X$ to be $X$=[$J$ $X$*]  where $J$ is a *($n$,$1$)* vector of all $1$'s, and $X$* is a *($n$,$p$)* matrix.

Let $H_X$ be a projection matrix, where $H_X$ = $X{(X'X)}^{-1}X'$.

I'm trying to prove:

> $H_X$ = $H_J$ + $H_X*$

And in doing so, I've been trying to deduce the above equation using:

> Suppose the design matrix $X$ can be decomposed by columns as $X$= [$A$ $B$]. 
>   Define the hat or projection operator as $P${$X$} = $X{(X'X)}^{-1}X'$.
>   Similarly, define the residual operator as $M${$X$}=$I$-$P${$X$}. 
>   Then the projection matrix can be decomposed as follows:
>
> $P${$X$} = $P${$A$} + $P${$M${$A$}$B$}.

I found this formula (the "Blockwise Formula") on Wikipedia.
The link is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix

I've been trying to prove this formula, and from that deduce the equation I'm trying to solve. But I still haven't found a way to prove either.
How do you think I should prove the equation above? Will the formula I found on Wikipedia be helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: Not kosher to cross-post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830852/find-projection-matrix-using-partitioned-matrices .

Comment: You're going to have a hard time proving that a $p+1\times p+1$ matrix is the sum of a $1\times 1$ matrix and a $p\times p$ matrix!  This suggests the first thing to clear up is the meaning of "$+$" in the formula you're trying to prove.